# Using cpu 100 percent issue while implementing async C# HTTP server

Tags: c#, node.js, http

I'm trying to implement http server using C# like in NodeJs.
In NodeJs, I've implement async http server as follows.

```
var config = require('./config'),
    cluster = require('cluster'),
    dgwLogger = require('./modules/dgwLogger'),
    healthChecker = require('./modules/healthChecker'),
    crashLogger = require('./modules/crashLogger');

module.exports = exports = getWorkerID = function() {
    return cluster.worker === null ? 0 : cluster.worker.id;
}

if (config.useCluster && cluster.isMaster) {
    var cpuNum;
    if (typeof config.useCluster === 'number')
        cpuNum = config.useCluster;
    else
        cpuNum = require('os').cpus().length;
    for (var i = 0; i < cpuNum; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
        cluster.fork();
    });
} else {
    var express = require('express'),
        http = require('http'),
    var app = express();

    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(sendResJson);
    app.use(express.errorHandler());

    app.post("/auth/getPJCharacter", gameServer.getPJCharacter);
    app.post("/auth/addPJCharacter", gameServer.addPJCharacter);

    setTimeout(function() { 
        http.createServer(app).listen(config.pjoa.port, function() {
            checkHealth();
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

The code just creates all thread according to cpu counts and express module listens to single port. Whenever there is request from port, cluster sends requests to separate thread automatically.
I heard this method is efficient to handle multiple request. But right now, I'm using C# on client side, so I wanted to use server side language as C# also, because I'm doing one man project and it's hard to use different language between server and client.
The below code is C# version.

```
class Program{
        static void Main (string[] args){
            WebServerMain main = new WebServerMain ();
            main.Init ();
        }
    }
    public class WebServerMain{
        private static WebServerMain singleton;
        public static WebServerMain Instance{
            get{
                return singleton;
            }
        }
        const int MAX_WORKERS = 2;
        AsyncHttpServer[] threadList = new AsyncHttpServer[MAX_WORKERS];
        public MySqlTest SqlManager;
        public MemAccessor MemManager;
        public TGBaseData BaseData;
        public WebServerMain (){}
        public void Init(){
            singleton = this;
            SqlManager = new MySqlTest ();
            MemManager = new MemAccessor ();
            MemManager.Init ();
            BaseData = new TGBaseData ();
            BaseData.Load ();
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_WORKERS; i++) {
                threadList [i] = new AsyncHttpServer ();
                threadList[i].ID = i;
            }                                 
            StartLoop ();
        }
        public void StartLoop(){
            HttpListener listener = new HttpListener ();
            listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8081/");
            listener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine ("Server Started at localHost");
            while (true) {
                HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
                AsyncHttpServer temp = GetLessWorkingThread ();
                temp.QueueRequest (context);
            }
        }
        AsyncHttpServer GetLessWorkingThread(){
            int index = 0;
            int min = 1000000000;
            for (int i = 0; i < threadList.Length; i++) {
                if (threadList [i].TotalProcessing < min) {
                    min = threadList [i].TotalProcessing;
                    index = i;
                }
            }
            return threadList [index];
        }
    }
public class AsyncHttpServer
    {
        public int ID;
        public int TotalProcessing;
        //Queue
        MarshalSyncContext curSyncContext;
        Queue<HttpListenerContext> contextQueue;
        Thread loopThread;
        Dictionary<int,HttpListenerContext> contextDic;
        Dictionary<string,ServiceTaskDelegate> serviceDic;

        public AsyncHttpServer (){
            contextDic = new Dictionary<int, HttpListenerContext> ();
            contextQueue = new Queue<HttpListenerContext> ();

            serviceDic = new Dictionary<string,ServiceTaskDelegate> ();
            MainLoginService.AddService (serviceDic);
            ThrowGameMainService.AddService (serviceDic);

            loopThread = new Thread (DoListeningWork);
            loopThread.Start ();
        }
        public void QueueRequest(HttpListenerContext context){
            TotalProcessing++;
            contextQueue.Enqueue (context);
        }
        void DoListeningWork(){
            curSyncContext = new MarshalSyncContext ();
            while (true) {
                if (contextQueue.Count > 0) {
                    HttpListenerContext context = contextQueue.Dequeue ();
//                  Console.WriteLine ("Context=" + context.GetType ().ToString ());
                    Task req = ProcessRequest (context);
                    contextDic.Add (req.Id, context);
                    req.ContinueWith (task => {
                        TotalProcessing--;
                        HttpListenerContext tempContext = contextDic[ task.Id ];
                        contextDic.Remove(task.Id);
                        if(task.IsFaulted == true){
                            task.Exception.Handle( exception =>{
                                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                                Console.WriteLine(exception.StackTrace);
                                return true;
                            });
                            XElement temp = new XElement("Root",
                                new XElement("Err",Err.INTERNAL_ERROR));
                            WriteSimpleText(tempContext, temp.ToString());
                            tempContext.Response.Close();
                        }
                    });
                }
                curSyncContext.ProcessAwaitProcedures ();
                Thread.Sleep (1000);
            }
        }
```

Inside AsyncHttpServer class, class makes single thread and check for queue data given from WebServerMain loop. But while waiting for queue, I've used while(true) for wait for queue, but this gives the result of this program to run in full CPU resource. (If I set 4 multithread, then it uses 400% of CPU).
I tried making Task thread whenever there is request, but this makes too many threads so I had to use this method.
Is there any way to not use full CPU?
Or is this right way to implement async Http server like NodeJS http server?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you've decided to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I'm making simple game that uses http server as scoring server. Client side language is C# because I'm using Unity game engine. I've used nodejs server in before project, but I had trouble between coding client and server with different language. And as I've mentioned, I'm doing this alone, so If the client and server language is differ, then I will have difficulties while colding. So I decided to use C# language as Server.

Comment: Right, and you're reinventing the wheel. You could write the web part as WebAPI and host it in IIS, which is a pre-existing, robust, scalable web server. Are you planning on writing your own SQL database engine, as well, or are you going to use an existing SQL engine?

Comment: Yes your right about reinventing the wheel. I had some reason with that decision.
1.IIS and WebAPI needs to be executed on Windows Server OS. And I was totally new with Windows Server.
2.I was familier to linux environment(I'm using Mac as my computer), and if I decide Windows Server, I need to use MsSQL as well, and these are all need to be run in Windows Server.

Comment: Look at ASP.NET 5, which is cross-platform and will run on Linux.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I'll look into it.